# XSLT 2.0 changing the default namespace value of ROOT after applying templates

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0, xslt-3.0

My goal is to be able to :

1. Replace root element's `xmlns="http://xmlns.example.com/v1"` with `xmlns="http://xmlns.example.com"` (**without v1**)
2. Replace root element's `schemaVersion="1"`with `schemaVersion="2"` **(version 2)**
3. Apply the other **template match** to exclude (not add) the nodes I need to remove from input xml.

**Input xml**

```
<account xmlns="http://xmlns.example.com/v1" 
        xmlns:ns2="http://xmlns.example/v2"
        schemaVersion="1">
    <head>Jane Doe</head>    
    <accountNumber>1234567</accountNumber>
    <messageType>CREATE</messageType>
    <create>
        <ns2:profile>
            <ns2:accountNumber>1234567</ns2:accountNumber>
        </ns2:profile>
    </create>
    <ns2:tax>
        <ns2:taxExempt>false</ns2:taxExempt>
    </ns2:tax>
    <contact>
        <ns2:address>US</ns2:address>
    </contact>
</account>
```

**Desired output xml**

```
<account xmlns="http://xmlns.example.com" 
        xmlns:ns2="http://xmlns.example/v2"
        schemaVersion="2">
    <head>Jane Doe</head>    
    <messageType>ADD</messageType>
    <action>A</action>
        <ns2:profile>
            <ns2:accountNumber>1234567</ns2:accountNumber>
        </ns2:profile>
    <contact>
        <ns2:address>US</ns2:address>
    </contact>
</account>
```

In the desired output, I

1. Changed root element first namespace value from `xmlns="http://xmlns.example.com/v1"` to `xmlns="http://xmlns.example.com"` **(without v1)**
2. Changed root element's `schemaVersion` attribute value from `schemaVersion="1"` to `schemaVersion="2"` **(version 2)**
3. Removed `<accountNumber>`
4. Changed `<messageType>` value from **CREATE** to **ADD**
5. Added `<action>A</action>`
6. Removed parent node `<create>` but **kept** its children node.
7. Removed entire `<ns2:tax>` node and its children

I managed to produce the desired output. However, it **introduced a problem**.

**Problem** : In current output xml, `xmlns="http://xmlns.example.com/v1"` **(version 1)** was added to `<head>` and `<contact>`.

`xmlns="http://xmlns.example.com/v1"` **should go away**.

**Current Output from my xsl**

```
<account xmlns="http://xmlns.example.com" 
        xmlns:ns2="http://xmlns.example/v2"
        schemaVersion="2">
    <head xmlns="http://xmlns.example.com/v1">Jane Doe</head>    
    <messageType>ADD</messageType>
    <action>A</action>
        <ns2:profile>
            <ns2:accountNumber>1234567</ns2:accountNumber>
        </ns2:profile>
    <contact xmlns="http://xmlns.example.com/v1">
        <ns2:address>US</ns2:address>
    </contact>
</account>
```

**My XSL Code**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xpath-default-namespace="http://xmlns.example.com/v1"
    xmlns:ns2="http://xmlns.example/v2">

    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

    <!-- Copy all text nodes, elements and attributes -->
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Replace root's xmlns and schemaVersion value -->
    <xsl:template match="account">
        <account xmlns="http://xmlns.example.com" 
                 xmlns:ns2="http://xmlns.example/v2"
                 schemaVersion="2">
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </account>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <!-- remove <accountNumber> -->
    <xsl:template match="accountNumber" />
    
    <!-- Change messageType value from CREATE to ADD -->
    <!-- Add <action>A</action> -->
    <xsl:template
        match="account/messageType[text()='CREATE']">
        <xsl:element name='messageType'
            namespace='http://xmlns.example.com'>
            <xsl:value-of select="'ADD'" />
        </xsl:element>
        <xsl:element name='action'
            namespace='http://xmlns.example.com'>
            <xsl:value-of select="'A'" />
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <!-- remove node <create> but keep its children -->
    <xsl:template match="create">
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:template>
    
    <!-- Removed entire <ns2:tax> node and its children -->
    <xsl:template match="ns2:tax" />

    <!-- Ensure that the namespace of nodes prefixed with ns2 has "http://xmlns.example/v2" value --> 
    <xsl:template match="ns2:*">
        <xsl:element name="ns2:{local-name()}"
            namespace="http://xmlns.example/v2">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*, node()" />
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I'm having difficulty because I had to set `xpath-default-namespace="http://xmlns.example.com/v1"` to version 1 first to match the nodes I want to remove AND I then eventually I need to replace the xmlns value to the **not version 1** (`xmlns="http://xmlns.example.com/"`)

I'd appreciate any suggestion or thoughts on solving this.

Thank you.

Comment: Is the `mesageType` the used and wanted spelling or is an `s` missing i.e. it should be `messageType`?

Comment: @MartinHonnen Sorry, it's just a typo. It is `messageType` I updated the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The identity transformation alone doesn't help if you want or need to change the namespaces of elements (and a namespace declared on some element applies to all its descendants so you need to change the namespace of the root and all its descendants); based on that I think you need to write a templates as the starting point that change the element namespace:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns="http://xmlns.example.com"
    xmlns:v1="http://xmlns.example.com/v1"
    xpath-default-namespace="http://xmlns.example.com/v1"
    xmlns:ns2="http://xmlns.example/v2"
    exclude-result-prefixes="v1">

    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />
        
    <xsl:template match="/*/@schemaVersion">
      <xsl:attribute name="{name()}">2</xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <!-- Change namespace http://xmlns.example.com/v1 to http://xmlns.example.com-->
    <xsl:template match="v1:*">
        <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
          <xsl:copy-of select="namespace::*[not(. = 'http://xmlns.example.com/v1')]"/>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <!-- remove <accountNumber> -->
    <xsl:template match="accountNumber" />
    
    <!-- Change messageType value from CREATE to ADD -->
    <!-- Add <action>A</action> -->
    <xsl:template
        match="account/mesageType[.='CREATE']">
        <messageType>ADD</messageType>
        <action>A</action>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <!-- remove node <create> but keep its children -->
    <xsl:template match="create">
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="ns2:*">
      <xsl:copy copy-namespaces="no">
        <xsl:copy-of select="namespace::*[not(. = 'http://xmlns.example.com/v1')]"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <!-- Removed entire <ns2:tax> node and its children -->
    <xsl:template match="ns2:tax" />

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I tried to gradually add each line of code to my xsl file on Eclipse. For some reason, I am getting an `invalid element` on `<xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>`
I tried changing the version to `<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" ..` but I get a `schema-for-xslt30.xsd` error on the version declaration line.

Comment: @heisenberg, the question has the tag for XSLT 3.0 so I assumed you are using an XSLT 3.0 processor like Saxon 9.8 or later or Saxon JS 2 or AltovaXML 2017 R3 or later. But for your particular use case I think you can drop the `<xsl:mode/>` declaration my sample has, it was more in there from a template I use for XSLT 3.

Comment: I appreciate the clarification.
In my `pom.xml` the only saxon dependency I added was 
`<dependency>`
    `<groupId>net.sf.saxon</groupId>`
    `<artifactId>Saxon-HE</artifactId>`
    `<version>10.6</version>`
`</dependency>`
which I believe should be version 3.0. I just happen to create an xsl file version 2.0

But I'll follow your advice to just drop the `<xsl:mode/>` and try to see if all will generate fine.

Comment: @heisenberg, yes, Saxon 10.6 does XSLT 3 completely fine so any errors about a schema are from your IDE in an attempt to syntax check or validate the XSLT code but certainly not from Saxon HE.

Comment: I haven't used the `namespace:: ...` before. I'm not sure if this is recognizable only in version 3.0. I am getting an `Xpath is invalid` error in 
`select="namespace::*[not(. = 'http://xmlns.example.com/v1')]"`
Could you tell me how to fix this or make it compatible with Eclipse please.
I read online and see that Eclipse only supports version 2.0 at present.

Comment: @heisenberg, I don't think the use of the namespace axis has changed since XSLT 1.0, my suggestion https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/gVTWaz9 seems to do the job with Saxon 10.6, I can't really tell what Eclipse supports or how to get it to support XSLT 2 or 3.

Comment: The `xsltfiddle..` link was useful. I bookmarked it.
For whatever reason, Eclipse marks the `namespace::*....` as invalid xpath when you have the xsl file opened in the editor. 
When I run the program, it was still able to process it correctly. I was able to generate the expected output
I guess it's an Eclipse warning/issue but not really an error. I'll just ignore that message in Eclipse.
Issue is now solved. Thanks for all the help.